# Skew symmetric matrix decomposes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, determinant

I am supposed to show that for a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ with $det(A) \neq 0$, meaning that is has an even number of columns and rows, there is an invertible matrix $ R $ such that  $ R^T A R = M$, where $M$ is a block matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & Id &  \\
-Id & 0 & 
\end{bmatrix}$.

This excercise is so general that I don't know which approach/idea or observation is useful to solve this excercise.

Comment: $Id$ denotes the identity of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A skew-symmetric matrix $A$ creates an alternating bilinear form $B(x,y):=x^TAy$.

A full discussion of these, including the reexpression of $A$ into a basis so that the matrix has that block form is [in *Basic Algebra I*](http://books.google.com/books?id=JHFpv0tKiBAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=basic+algebra+jacobson&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HieNUYGrIKK5ywG_oID4CA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=skew%20symmetric&f=false) by Jacobson, starting on page 349.

Added: Ah, here's another set of [brief notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/LinearAlgebra/2008-2009/bilinear-08.pdf) which I think has the details.

I didn't spend long enough to confirm it, but it also *has* to be in [Keith Conrad's notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf) on bilinear forms somewhere...